# Where is MvcServiceLocator in ASP.NET MVC 3 RC?

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-3, service-locator

I'm trying to incorporate Ninject with my ASP.NET MVC 3 RC application.

From the tutorials I found, I'm supposed to set the ServiceLocator via

```
MvcServiceLocator.SetCurrent
```

in the `Global.asax` file, but I can't seem to find this in ASP.NET MVC 3 RC. Has this been changed to something else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The design for this feature has changed. The following blog post should answer your questions: http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/service-location-pt5-idependencyresolver.html